# Trying to insert multiple rows in References table getting error IDENTITY_INSERT

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

So what I am trying to do is I am getting a post list with id's and looping it and adding it in the database using Linq EFcore but I am getting an error when there are multiple id's in the post if there is only one it works fine.

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,IsPublished,CretedDate,ModifiyDate,posts")] Tag tag,List<int> posts)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        foreach (var item in posts)
        {
            var _post = _contextPosts.dbcontext.Post.Find(item); // fetch one record from posts 
            tag.PostTag = new List<PostTag> //Tag
            {
                 new PostTag 
                 {
                      Post = _post,
                      Tag = tag
                      }
            };
            
            _contextTags.dbcontext.Add(tag);

            await _contextTags.dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

[image: ni]

**Tables**

```cs
public class Post
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Created By:")]
    public AppUser AuthorId { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string metaTitle { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; } = true;
    public bool IsFeatured { get; set; } = false;
    public DateTime CretedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime ModifiyDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public ICollection<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public ICollection<PostTag> Tags { get; set; }
}

public class Tag
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsPublished { get; set; } = true;
    public DateTime CretedDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public DateTime ModifiyDate { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public ICollection<PostTag> PostTag { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Images> Images { get; set; }
}

public class PostTag
{
    public int TagId { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public Post Post { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }
    public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I'm confused by your structure. `tag` contains a list of `PostTags`. And the first and only item in that list has a `tag` property... which is the original `tag` itself. It looks like you're doing something circular... Can you please post the structure (simplified) of the 3 classes.

Comment: I think also, the singular and plural forms are confusing. `_posts` (plural) is using `.Find()`, so it will never have more than 1 record (singular). And `PostTag` (singular) is a `List<PostTag>` (plural)

Comment: Sorry about that i just quickly wrote that for testing purpose please have look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you already have some posts records in your database, and you want to attach these posts to the tag.

For this case, you can first add the tag to `Tag` table, and retrieve Id of the newest inserted Tag entity. Then insert the TagId and PostId to PostTag Table.

Refer to the below code:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    List<int> posts = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    Tag tag = new Tag
    {
        Name = "T1",
        IsPublished = true,
        CretedDate = DateTime.Now,
        ModifiyDate = DateTime.Now
    };

    _context.Tag.Add(tag);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    int tagId = tag.Id;

    foreach (var item in posts)
    {
        _context.PostTag.Add(new PostTag { TagId = tagId, PostId = item });
        await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

    return View();
}
```

**dbo.Post:**

[image]

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that `PostTags` is a many-to-many intermediary table for `Post`s and `Tags`. I don't think you should be updating that manually; it's easier to build your object structure, and let Entity Framework add the intermediary records. So something more like:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Name,IsPublished,CretedDate,ModifiyDate,posts")] Tag tag, List<int> posts)
    {
    
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            foreach (var item in posts)
            {
                var post = _dbcontext.Post.Find(item);
                post.Tags.Add(tag);

                await _dbcontext.SaveChangesAsync();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

The error indicates that the you are trying to save a `Tag` entity which already has a primary key set. That means you are not trying to *create* new `Tag` - the Tag already exists in the database, you are just linking it to the Posts.

If that is the case, then -

1. fetch the existing `Tag` first along with its `PostTag` collection
2. add each newly created `PostTag` to the existing `PostTag` collection
3. save the existing `Tag`

```cs
// Fetch existing Tag including its PostTag collection
var existingTag = await context.Tags.Include(p => p.PostTags).FirstOrDefaultAsync(p => p.Id == tag.Id);

foreach (var item in posts)
{
    var existingPost = await context.Posts.FindAsync(item.Id);
    
    // Add to the existing PostTag collection
    existingTag.PostTags.Add(new PostTag { Post = existingPost });
}

// Save existing Tag
await context.SaveChangesAsync();
```